# determining size of bit block in c

Tags: c, plaintext, encryption, strlen

I am implementing a primitive block cipher. However, the implementation is such that the size of the ciphertext may differ from the size of plaintext. I need to know how I can calculate the size of the ciphertext that is formed after encoding. strlen(char *) will not work since the ciphertext may contain multiple '\n' characters. Is there any work-around this problem?

Comment: strlen has no problem with embedded '\n'. Do you mean embedded '\0' characters?

Comment: I don't understand - if you are implementing the cipher, how can you not know how big the output block is?  If you mean 'how can I parse out the blocks on decoding', you will have to implement some protocol to wrap the blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Your encoding function should return the size, it's the one and only entity that knows it. 
Implementing a separate function to "find out the size" would mean reimplementing half of the algorithm.

So if in your encoding function you have something like this:

```
while (...)
    buf[i++] = stuff;
```

You should return `i`.

Comment: The one and very only good answer...